# symfony2 method undefined in EntityRepository

Tags: php, symfony

i want create a request from my EntityRepository so this is my code:

```
<?php

namespace zhr\myprojectBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * myprojectdbEntityRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class myprojectdbEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getAll()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');

        $query = $qb;

        $result = $qb->getQuery()->execute();

    }
}
```

i want use it in my controller file so this is my code:

public function searchusersAction(Request $request)
    {

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('myprojectBundle:User');


    $utilisateur = $repository->getAll();

   var_dump($utilisateur); die();

    //return $this->render('mypageBundle:Admin:adminindex.html.twig', array('sheet'=>$utilisateur));

}
```

i get a error:

Undefined method 'getAll'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

??? normaly all methode in repository file must be defined in my controller file no ?

thanks first guys

Comment: Do you have set the repositoryClass in your entity? http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html

Comment: I think the error is self explanatory. The method name should start with findBy or findOneBy not get. And you're not returning anything form getAll method

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `getResult()` to return a result as follow:

```
public function getAll()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

But you really don't need this kind of function since `EntityRepository` class already has `findAll()` function to get all rows from an entity:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$rows = $em->getRepository('myprojectBundle:User')->findAll();
```

I suggest you to check documentation for [QueryBuilder](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html) and [EntityRepository](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html) api.